# NSIS convert string into fixed length Code

Tags: nsis

I have info that I encrypt and would like to convert that to a fixed format

Example String: 
`IQIphBbUPPQrLdehz1JEB6a3yj4pCuDNhpHPfBAxVuYeDKlaK7mOuB40RxHpdmBVj33iMTk8GZ+/ShJdoWJcUPxlCZXIPue2JgOoGv+LXpvCcL724h7nsxSu2JoltXMm4VZ3HUwCLsOrEP7h6f2Q6ZFBqII43WzHL4f2LRjQIioFD/eE7kcgY104Axlj0Gcw`

I would like to convert that into a format like: (0-9 A-Z)
`0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000`

So output would look something like:
`0D1Z-52CV-8645-8256-428S-RTG6-452D`

Similar to Hex output but at a fixed length.

Is this possible? Note: encrypted string will vary in length.

Comment: Do you need to be able to get the original string back or do you just need a one way function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a one way function/[cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)/message digest then you can just use [one of the plug-ins](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Crypto_plug-in) from the NSIS Wiki:

```
Crypto::HashData "SHA1" "IQIphBbUPPQrLdehz1JEB6a3yj4pCuDNhpHPfBAxVuYeDKlaK7mOuB40RxHpdmBVj33iMTk8GZ+/ShJdoWJcUPxlCZXIPue2JgOoGv+LXpvCcL724h7nsxSu2JoltXMm4VZ3HUwCLsOrEP7h6f2Q6ZFBqII43WzHL4f2LRjQIioFD/eE7kcgY104Axlj0Gcw"
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0 ; A598CAB0215FFD7E27551515FA3DAF8D5AFD6D27
```

You can format these hex bytes in any way you want:

```
Crypto::HashData "MD5" "IQIphBbUPPQrLdehz1JEB6a3yj4pCuDNhpHPfBAxVuYeDKlaK7mOuB40RxHpdmBVj33iMTk8GZ+/ShJdoWJcUPxlCZXIPue2JgOoGv+LXpvCcL724h7nsxSu2JoltXMm4VZ3HUwCLsOrEP7h6f2Q6ZFBqII43WzHL4f2LRjQIioFD/eE7kcgY104Axlj0Gcw"
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0 ; A709E7B1FF62582B7B97632F71912EB8 (MD5 is shorter but less secure)

StrCpy $1 ""
StrCpy $3 0
loop:
StrCpy $2 $0 4 $3
IntOp $3 $3 + 4
StrCmp $2 "" done
StrCpy $1 "$1-$2"
StrLen $2 $2
IntCmpU $2 4 loop done loop
done:
StrCpy $1 $1 "" 1
DetailPrint $1 ; A709-E7B1-FF62-582B-7B97-632F-7191-2EB8
```

If on the other hand you want to get back the original input string then what you want to do is simply not possible. After you have hashed something you can only compare it with other hashes, you cannot (easily) figure out the initial input. There can also be collisions where two different inputs will generate the same output hash (The string "Hello" could in theory have the same hash as a the complete contents of a phone book etc.).

Comment: Yes just one way. And the second way with the formatting is just what I needed.it works great. But with the possibility off one string matching another string once hashed is very small correct? I am using this to create a type of computer fingerprint. the odds would be 32 to the 36 power "1.5324955408e+54" I think thats good enough odds?

Comment: Yes the chance is very small. MD5 is considered to be broken because people with a bit of computing power can create collisions on purpose.